# How to fix: yum install with error in docker container?

Tags: docker, yum

I just would like to try to install sshd in centos:latest image.

I try to install 'passwd', typing the command like this:

`yum install passwd`

But I have a error like this:

```
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C.UTF-8
CentOS-8 - AppStream                            0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:30    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'AppStream':
  - Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=AppStream&infra=container [Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'AppStream': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=AppStream&infra=container [Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org]
```

I don't know why I can't install using yum in docker container?

Comment: and you did `yum update` before hand?

Comment: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/866

Comment: @codingwithmanny yes I did. But the same error.

Comment: Weird. Docker version and what OS are you running it on?

Comment: docker version 19.03.10, OS linux CentOS 8

Answer (score 1):

Masquerading allows for docker ingress and egress:

```
    firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-masquerade --permanent
```

Specifically allow incoming traffic on port 80/443 :

```
     firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=443/tcp
```

Reload firewall to apply permanent rules:

```
     firewall-cmd --reload
```

Restart docker :

```
     systemctl restart docker
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this on my local machine:

```sh
docker run -it -d --name test centos:latest;

docker exec -it test /bin/bash;
```

In docker container:

```sh
[root@f3b8b3fe70df /]# yum update -y;
[root@f3b8b3fe70df /]# yum install passwd;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add access to the host network using `--network host`

```
docker run --network host -it -d --name test centos:latest
```